# Почему нельзя использовать другой тип

Tags: c++

Я обнаружил, что если в классе метод возвращает ссылку, тогда с ним можно сделать такую вещь:

```
class A
{
public:
    enum ElementType
    {
        A2,
        A3,
    };
    A& Add(ElementType type)
    {
        std::cout << type << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{   
    A {}.Add(A::ElementType::A2).Add(A::ElementType::A3);
    return 0;
}
```

Почему я не мог так сделать, если будет тип `void`?

Comment: Потому что у типа `void` нет функции-члена`Append`, и это даже не классовый тип. По этой же причине нельзя сделать так: `int x; x.Append(1)`.

Comment: @wololo но если использовать `A {}.Add(A::ElementType::A2);` один раз, тогда все нолрмально, а если несколько, тогда уже не получается, тип `void`

Comment: Первый раз функция вызывается не у типа `void`, а у объекта типа `A`, который имеет функцию-член `Add`.

Comment: @wololo Все, до меня дошло, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Если метод возвращает ссылку на объект, то к нему применяется вызов следующего метода, а если метод возвращает тип void, то это означает, что возвращаемого значения нет и невозможно вызвать следующий метод.